# Python error type string

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a dataframe, DF of columns of data as such:

```
        X       Y         Z     DIST_1
0       309000  563250    0     681483125
1       309000  563300    0     679910525
2       309000  563350    0     678342925
```

Upon attempting to run math.sqrt on DIST_1 with the following

```
DF['DIST'] = math.sqrt(DF['DIST_1'])
```

I am getting

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I have tried running three separate functions, on the individual column and the entire DataFrame, to fix this problem:

```
DF['DIST_1'] = pd.to_numeric(DF['DIST_1'])

DF['DIST_1'] = (DF['DIST_1']).astype(float)

DF= DF.applymap(float)
```

Each of these appears to have the desired results of changing DIST_1 to a float. Here is the output after running

```
DF['DIST_1'] = (DF['DIST_1']).astype(float)

        X       Y         Z     DIST_1
0       309000  563250    0     681483125.0
1       309000  563300    0     679910525.0
2       309000  563350    0     678342925.0
```

Again I run

```
DF['DIST'] = math.sqrt(DF['DIST_1'])
```

but the result is again

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: Did you try the map function? I think sqrt only works on a number, not a pandas series, so maybe you could do it with the map function.

Comment: Yes. This changes all columns to floats but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `DF['DIST_1']` is this one a list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following

```
DF['DIST_1'] = DF['DIST_1'].apply(math.sqrt)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `math.sqrt` can only take a single number, not a `pandas.Series`. One way is to use `apply`, as [@Kalyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8898218/kalyan) recommended [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866664/4042267).

The easier solution is to use a function that can handle a vector of floats, [`numpy.sqrt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html):

```
import numpy as np
DF['DIST'] = np.sqrt(DF['DIST_1'])
```

This should also be significantly faster than repeatedly applying the `math.sqrt` function to every element of the series.